# Assembly code insertion in C standard functions

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker, c-standard-library

I'm currently working on a control-flow integrity framework on a custom-made RISC-V SoC. Mainly, I have some CSRs that I need to write at the beginning and the end of each function. I'm doing it now by inserting `CSRW` instructions directly within the assembly .S file generated by GCC. It works great with most parts but not with the C functions coming from standard libraries.

The problem is that these functions are not visible within the .S file; I can only see a `call` or a `tail` calling them, but not their actual implementation. Is there a GCC flag that I can use while compiling that would make these functions visible?

Comment: If needed on *any* function call, shouldn't actually the compiler generate the appropriate code for you? Or are you operating on a GCC variant actually for a different platform with otherwise equivalent instruction set?

Comment: I'm operating on regular GCC (11.1 from the RISC-V toolchain). I developed a framework to insert code within the .S file directly. The compiler has no such feature as I'm using a custom hardware implementation. Especially, the CSRs I'm writing on are unknown by GCC. Also, it's in _most_ of the functions, the developer should have some flexibility, so adding the feature directly within the compiler might not be an option.

Comment: GCC does not provide a standard C library.  Those calls are just that -- calls to external symbols.  The program is combined with the C library by the linker, (mostly) the same as for third-party libraries like zlib, libssl, etc. C library's source code is maintained by a different group of people, and I can't even tell you _which_ group of people because GCC can be used with several _different_ implementations of the standard library!  You're going to have to figure out which one you've got, find its source code, and recompile it with your special CSRW injector.

Comment: Thank you @zwol for the explanation. So no generic solution seems possible then, but more a case-by-case approach. I actually know where to find the object files .o on my system. Is there a way to "disassemble" these files into .S assembly files? Then it would just add an extra step to my current flow.

Comment: @NicoKart Information is discarded in the .S -> .o transformation, such as the locations of labels. I'm not aware of any disassembler that can reliably reconstruct enough of that lost information that you could modify the output and reassemble it.